# how to find the latest selected item of a multiple select tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a `<select multiple="multiple" id="multi">` in my website, and I have a script in jquery that has this function:

```
$("#multi").on("change",function(){})
```

I want to access the latest selected item of the `select` in this function(the last one selected by user), how can I do that?

Comment: The last, as in the last one selected by the user, or the last selected option in the HTML etc.

Comment: I mean the last one selected by user

Comment: Then you should probably answer the comments when they are posted, and test the answers before you accept them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the last selected by the user, you can do this

```
var map = $("#multi").on("change",function(){
    var comp = $("#multi option:selected").map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get(),
        set1 = map.filter(function(i) {
            return comp.indexOf(i) < 0;
        }),
        set2 = comp.filter(function(i) {
            return map.indexOf(i) < 0;
        }),
        last = (set1.length ? set1 : set2)[0];

    map = comp;

    // "last" contains the last one selected /unselected

}).find('option:selected').map(function() {return this.value}).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bwf5u3sj/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:selected` selector and `:last` (or alternatively `.last()`) this way:

```
$('#multi').change(function() {
  console.log( $(this).find('option:selected:last').text() );
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdibaiee/fmc5k109/)

Comment: no, this shows the last selected item in html, I want the latest selected item by user!

Comment: @Navid777 use `value()` instead of `text()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for this

```
$("#multi").on("change",function(){
    alert($("option:selected:last",this).val());    
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/72/)

Comment: no, this shows the last selected item in html, I want the latest selected item by user!

Comment: @Navid777 sorry ca you tell the diff I'm not getting.

Answer (score 1):

```
var last_value;   

 $('#multi').change(function() {
     last_value = this.val();
alert(last_value);
    });
```

define global variable, and every time ur dropdown change the seletion, u can replace the last selected value with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE :](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/bwf5u3sj/4/)

Less coding with Optimize solution : Why not use the `is` function of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#multi option').click(function(){        
        if($(this).is(':selected'))
            console.log('you have select' + $(this).val());
        else
            console.log('you have Unselect' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var = last;
$('#multi').find('option').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if($(this).hasAttr('selected')) {
            last = $(this);
        }
    }
}
```